# SwiftUI - Schedule a notification to repeat after an specific date

Tags: swift, swiftui, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm a SwiftUI beginner. I'm creating an app and in the add view, the user can pick a date to start the notifications and in a picker list choose how often it repeats, like 15 min, 1 hour, 2 hours, etc. I did create the part that it schedule the first notification, but I don't know how to create another notification that repeats after this first one happens.

Here's my code

```
private func scheduleNotification(medication: Medication) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound])  {
            success, error in
                if success {
                    print("authorization granted")
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
    }
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Lembrete"
    content.body = "Tomar \(medication.name ?? "Medicamento")"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    
    guard let timeInterval = medication.date?.timeIntervalSinceNow else {return}
    
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: false)
    
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: medication.id!, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: So after the first notification, you want to have it repeat on regular intervals. Can you post what you think should work, what you've tried/ researched, etc?

Comment: It’s like the default iOS reminder app, for example it’s 6p.m and I want to schedule a reminder to 8 p.m that repeats every 8 hours, if I schedule the repeat notification it will schedule a reminder for 8 hours after 6 p.m not 8 right? That’s where my problem is at

Comment: I tried using a timer using the same timeInterval, and then schedule a new trigger with repetition, but it didn’t work, I guess the timer won’t work with the app on background

Answer (score 0):

when the notifications should send every "timeInterval" you just have to set the parameter `repeats` in `trigger` to true.

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true)
```

EDIT:
I also found an article: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/21/2/scheduling-notifications-unusernotificationcenter-and-unnotificationrequest

Comment: But the time interval that the trigger has is set to be the difference between the date that the user picked and now, not custom values like 1 hour, 4 hours, every day